# android code i am like trying to calculate but when i initialize cal1() method in itemselection listener case0 it crashes please tell me solution

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    Spinner s1,s2;
    TextView t1,t2,t3;
    String ops1,ops2;
    String[] op1={"Inclusive","+3%","+5%","+12%","+18%","+28%"};
    String[] op2={"Exclusive","-3%","-5%","-12%","-18%","-28%"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,adapter2;
EditText e1,et1,et2,et3;
Button b1;
double a,b,c,x;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, op1);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);


        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.s2);
        adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, op2);
        s2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tc);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ts);
        t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ti);


        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1) ;
        et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);




        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                t1.setText("CGST");
                t2.setText("SGST");
                t3.setText("IGST");

            }
        });

      s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              switch (position)
              {
                  case 0:

                      t1.setText("CGST(1.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(1.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(3%)");

                      cal1(); //error pop due to this

                      break;
                  case 1:

                      t1.setText("CGST(2.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(2.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(5%)");
                      break;
                  case 2:

                      t1.setText("CGST(6%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(6%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(12%)");

                      break;
                  case 3:
                      t1.setText("CGST(9%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(9%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(18%)");
                      break;
                  case 4:

                      t1.setText("CGST(14%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(14%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(28%)");
                      break;
              }



          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

          }
      });


      s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              switch (position)
              {
                  case 0:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-1.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-1.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-3%)");
                      break;
                  case 1:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-2.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-2.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-5%)");
                      break;
                  case 2:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-6%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-6%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-12%)");

                      break;
                  case 3:
                      t1.setText("CGST(-9%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-9%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-18%)");
                      break;
                  case 4:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-14%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-14%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-28%)");
                      break;
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

          }
      });

    }

    private void cal1()
    {

        x=Double.parseDouble(e1.getText().toString()); //from here

    }


}
```

please look to // error like it crashes the app 
Android code I am like trying to calculate but when I initialize cal1() method in item selection listener case:0 it crashes please tell me the solution
After getting the solution please give a certain suggestion
After going on a different method it again crashes

Comment: what crash log prints?

Comment: Please give your question a better summary! Also remove those useless dots and provide a backtrace instead (you say the program crashes).

Comment: Hi i am sry i was running late that's y i inserted... now the condition is that i want to access a method for case 1: like public void call(){double x=Double.parsedouble(edittext) //in my code edittext is e1 } and when i call it in case 1 my app crashes –

Answer (score 0):

->In your code change your switch cases from {0,1,2,3,4} to {1,2,3,4,5} because position 0 is for the index 0th of your array.

```
 s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              switch (position)
              {
                  case 1:

                      t1.setText("CGST(1.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(1.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(3%)");

                      cal1(); //error pop due to this

                      break;
                  case 2:

                      t1.setText("CGST(2.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(2.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(5%)");
                      break;
                  case 3:

                      t1.setText("CGST(6%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(6%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(12%)");

                      break;
                  case 4:
                      t1.setText("CGST(9%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(9%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(18%)");
                      break;
                  case 5:

                      t1.setText("CGST(14%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(14%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(28%)");
                      break;
              }



          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

          }
      });


      s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

              switch (position)
              {
                  case 1:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-1.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-1.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-3%)");
                      break;
                  case 2:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-2.5%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-2.5%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-5%)");
                      break;
                  case 3:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-6%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-6%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-12%)");

                      break;
                  case 4:
                      t1.setText("CGST(-9%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-9%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-18%)");
                      break;
                  case 5:

                      t1.setText("CGST(-14%)");
                      t2.setText("SGST(-14%)");
                      t3.setText("IGST(-28%)");
                      break;
              }
          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

          }
      });
```

-> always try to debug your code and find out errors. this will help to easily find out your errors.

Comment: ok thanks now if suppose i want to access a method for case 1: like public void call(){double x=Double.parsedouble(edittext) //in my code edittext is e1 } and when i call it in case 1 my app crashes